# How to get Mavenized JCuda, Eclipse, and Windows to work together?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jcuda

1. NVidia does not distribute the NSight IDE for Windows (only Linux and MacOSX)
2. I don't want to use Visual Studio because I'm not familiar with it; being a Java developer I prefer Eclipse.
3. I want to use Maven, because well everyone should, and [Mavenized JCuda](https://github.com/MysterionRise/mavenized-jcuda) seems like a good start.

So here's what I did:

1. Downloaded version 6.5 of CUDA Developer Toolkit from the [NVidia website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).
2. Got Eclipse J2EE edition, because it has built-in Maven support.
3. Cloned the mavenized-jcuda project into my workspace.
4. Tried to run the example program, but got errors.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load the native library.
Error while loading native library "JCudaRuntime-windows-x86_64" with base name "JCudaRuntime"
...
java.lang.NullPointerException: No resource found with name '/lib/JCudaRuntime-windows-x86_64.dll'
...
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JCudaRuntime-windows-x86_64 in java.library.path
...
```

I tried adding a bunch of paths to my -Djava.library.path="..." JVM argument, including:

- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\lib\x64
- etc...

But still getting the same error. What's even more concerning is that there is no such file anywhere on my computer by that name (JCudaRuntime-windows-x86_64.dll). So how do I resolve these linking issues?

Comment: Does the test that is described on the github site work for your (basically `mvn clean package` and then `mvn exec:exec` at the console), or does it also result in an UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Comment: Running through Maven alone is successful. Sorry for not mentioning that. But not through eclipse, even with Maven dependency management enabled.

Comment: I only tried it on the console until now, but if there's no answer until tomorrow, I'll give it a try in eclipse. In any case, the `-Djava.library.path` should point to the directory that contains the native *JCuda* DLL files (this will probably be in some "`target/lib`" subdirectory that is created by Maven during the build)

Comment: so, the problem is only if you try to run it inside Eclipse?

Comment: @JamesWatkins, could you list you target/lib directory?

Comment: Added the following to JVM arguments: -Djava.library.path=${workspace_loc:mavenized-jcuda}\target\lib now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: but maven should do it itself without adding java.library.path, that's the trick of mavenized jcuda itself :) could you please provide more information on how you run mavenized jcuda project?

Comment: @Mysterion, I wanted to invoke the app from eclipse without getting Maven involed (for cleaner console output). So I just had to duplicate the JVM arg from the exec config in the pom.xml to the eclipse run config and it worked. At least now Google will have a search result when someone has the same problem :)

Comment: One more thing, just in case it helps anyone, if you go to Project->Properties->Java Build Path->src/main/java->Native library location and add the /target/lib folder, you don't need to edit your run configurations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70274/discussion-between-james-watkins-and-mysterion).

Comment: @Mysterion or James Please add your answer as an answer.